# Where does Windows 8 store the estimated data usage over Wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, powershell

I accidentally discovered that in Windows 8, if you right-click a previously connected wireless network from the Start screen interface, there's an option to show estimated data usage.

[image]

[image]

Where's this data stored? Is it possible to fetch this via PowerShell/WMI? A use case for me would be to setup automated alerts based on data usage - I currently use [Networx](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/manual/?lang=English) for a more detailed breakdown, but for a quick alert, if I can fetch the usage, the automated route would help a lot.

Comment: I wonder why it's only *estimated*.

Comment: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Network\DataUsage\Wlan` looks related. I'm still searching.

Comment: It is related, but my research shows it's purely gui related, haven't seen anything on where the actual estimate is stored. nothing on google for that reg key except one result at this time.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Probably they call it estimated because it may show a different number than your ISP. Possibly they're guessing at some percent overhead as well (which Windows can't measure, as its being added elsewhere)

Answer (score 3):

I remember when you first asked this question, but I finally got around to figuring it out. Hope it's still of use to you or someone else!

You can access the this data by calling the [GetLocalUsage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br207253.aspx) method of [ConnectionProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile.aspx) objects, which are WLAN/WAN connections (i.e. SSIDs). GetLocalUsage takes two DateTime parameters and returns a [DataUsage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.datausage.aspx) object containing the amount of data sent and received during the interval specified. You can get a list of ConnectionProfile objects by calling the [GetConnectionProfiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getconnectionprofiles) method of [NetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.aspx).

I wrote the following function that retrieves the data and returns an object. Pass to it one or more SSIDs and optionally start and stop DateTime's:

```powershell
function Get-EstimatedDataUsage()
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$ProfileName,

        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$false)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [DateTime]$From,

        [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$false)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [DateTime]$To
    )

    Process
    {
        foreach($profile in $ProfileName)
        {
            try
            {
                [void][Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation,Windows,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
                $ConnectionProfiles = [Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation]::GetConnectionProfiles() | Where-Object ProfileName -EQ $profile
            }
            catch
            {
                Write-Error 'Unable to create instance of Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.'
                continue
            }

            foreach($ConnectionProfile in $ConnectionProfiles)
            {
                $ProfileName = $ConnectionProfile.ProfileName

                if($From -eq $null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        $ResetTime = Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Network\DataUsage\Wlan\$ProfileName -Name ResetTime -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResetTime
                        $From_determined = [datetime]::FromFileTime($ResetTime)
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        $From_determined = [datetime]::FromFileTime(0)
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $From_determined = $From
                }

                if($To -eq $null)
                {
                    $To_determined = Get-Date
                }
                else
                {
                    $To_determined = $To
                }

                $usage = $ConnectionProfile.GetLocalUsage($From_determined, $To_determined)

                $op = '' | select Name,Received,Sent,From,To

                $op.Name = $ProfileName
                $op.Received = $usage.BytesReceived
                $op.Sent = $usage.BytesSent
                $op.From = $From_determined
                $op.To = $To_determined

                $op

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This MSDN article is the best I could find from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.datausage.aspx. It tells you how you can call it from a program, but not where the data proper is stored. I'm not going to copy and paste it all because I don't know which language you prefer to program in.